# d3.js zoom transition with map tiles

Tags: d3.js, d3.geo

I'm trying to implement a zoom transition on a map that uses tiles. I want to zoom in on one location, then go back and forth between two other locations.

This is the example I'm working from: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6242308
That does what I want, only I wish to use map tiles instead of a topojson or geojson file.

Right now the map is calling the final location in the jump function, but the transitions between locations aren't working. Any idea on what's happening would be greatly welcomed-- nothing showing in console and I'm a bit stuck. Many thanks.

My code is below, and it's also in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3lUmsVgmL3yNXNGhw8T?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    #container {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #map{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    .layer {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .tile {
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 256px;
      height: 256px;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.tile.v0.min.js"></script>
    <div id="canvas">
        <div id="container">
            <g id="map">
                <div class="layer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

    var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
        height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight),
        prefix = prefixMatch(["webkit", "ms", "Moz", "O"]);

    var tile = d3.geo.tile()
        .size([width, height]);

    var sf = [-122.417, 37.775],
            belowsf = [-122.510962, 37.580284],
        ny = [-74.0064, 40.7142],
            brooklyn = [-73.975536, 40.691674];

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .scale(200000)
            .translate([-width / 2, -height / 2]); // just temporary

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom();

    var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
            .style("width", width + "px")
            .style("height", height + "px");

    var container = d3.select("#container")
        .style("width", width + "px")
        .style("height", height + "px");

    canvas

                    .call(zoomTo(ny,200300).event)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(20000)
                        .each(jump);

    var map = d3.select("#map");

    var layer = d3.select(".layer");

            function zoomTo(location, newscale) {
              return zoom
                    .scale((newscale) * 2 * Math.PI)
                    .translate(projection(location).map(function(x) { return -x; }));
            }

            function jump() {
              var t = d3.select(this);
              (function repeat() {
                t = t.transition()
                    .call(zoomTo(sf, 200000).event)
                  .transition()
                    .call(zoomTo(belowsf, 200000).event)
                    .each("end", repeat);
              })();
            }

    zoomed();

    function zoomed() {
      var tiles = tile
          .scale(zoom.scale())
          .translate(zoom.translate())
          ();

      projection
          .scale(zoom.scale() / 2 / Math.PI)
          .translate(zoom.translate());

      var image = layer
          .style(prefix + "transform", matrix3d(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
        .selectAll(".tile")
          .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });

      image.exit()
          .remove();

      image.enter().append("img")
          .attr("class", "tile")
          .attr("src", function(d) { return "http://" + ["a", "b", "c"][Math.random() * 3 | 0] + ".basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
          .style("left", function(d) { return (d[0] << 8) + "px"; })
          .style("top", function(d) { return (d[1] << 8) + "px"; });
    }


    function matrix3d(scale, translate) {
      var k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
      return "matrix3d(" + [k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, r(translate[0] * scale), r(translate[1] * scale), 0, 1 ] + ")";
    }

    function prefixMatch(p) {
      var i = -1, n = p.length, s = document.body.style;
      while (++i < n) if (p[i] + "Transform" in s) return "-" + p[i].toLowerCase() + "-";
      return "";
    }

    function formatLocation(p, k) {
      var format = d3.format("." + Math.floor(Math.log(k) / 2 - 2) + "f");
      return (p[1] < 0 ? format(-p[1]) + "°S" : format(p[1]) + "°N") + " "
           + (p[0] < 0 ? format(-p[0]) + "°W" : format(p[0]) + "°E");
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797)?

Comment: I have, thanks, but I don't want the user to be able to zoom or pan themselves. I want to transition between locations programatically, like in the block I linked to above-- only with tiles.

Comment: Well I don't think there's an example of *exactly* what you're looking for, but you should be able to combine functionality from the different examples to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I wrote the above code, with the map tiles, that uses the zoom transition functionality. What I'm stuck on is that the transitions don't seem to be working-- the map jumps straight to the last location in the jump function, without showing the other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of headscratching it turned out that the main thing was that you didn't actually tell the zoom behaviour to call the `zoomed` function:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);
```

This required moving some variable definitions such that everything is defined when this is called. Apart from that, you don't need to adjust the projection in the zoom handler, as the zoom of the tiles is achieved by setting a transform on the container.

Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8muX27u0kSnuPwtmmZlU?p=preview).

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thank you so much for taking the time to figure this out. I was doing a lot of head-scratching too, but not getting anywhere, so I really appreciate it.